# Facebook Graph API Error "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request" even if limit 1 and field 1 in query parameter

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all the video ids from the page. I am using v10.0 Graph API to achieve this.
Here is the API URL that I am requesting.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{{page_id}}/videos?limit=1&fields=id&access_token={{access_token}}
```

At the first request, it is giving me a proper response. Once, I request for another page, using the page_token that I get from the first response, it is giving me an error **"Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"**

I have checked many questioned related to this and tried to apply a limit of 1 on the query but still, the 2nd-page request is throwing the same error.

Please check the screenshot attached for more reference.
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!!!